# PHP Script Crashing Error

Tags: php, timeout

Okay so I'm trying to retrieve 130 XML files from a feed and then insert values into a database. Problem is, it crashes at around 40-60 entries and doesn't give an error. I timed it and the script goes for around 13 seconds each time.

I checked my php.ini settings and they are...

Memory Limit = 128M
Time Limit - 30 seconds

So what is causing this error? When I run the script on firefox it just displays a white screen.

EDIT - The error I'm getting on chrome is

> "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the
>   connection without sending any data"

Comment: Add an `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of the script and see if you get any errors...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the memory consumption?  Also could you do a writeline or output something to the screen to see that it's reading in the files?  Add error handling around the read statement to see if it's failing on parsing the XML.

Comment: I tried all of that, and I've just opened the script on chrome and this is the error Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

Comment: What protocol are you using to connect to the server, can you connect to it the same way outside of your app?